# Dataset of regexps with corresponding sentences

Tags: data-request, corpora, nlp

I'm looking for datasets that contain a list of regexps where each regexp is associated with at least one sentence written in English that explains what the regexp does. Examples:

- "All 3-letter words ending by .at except bat" can be expressed in regexp as `[^b]at`
- "Any word starting with the letter s" can be expressed in regexp as `s.*`

I am aware of the [dataset](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/rbg/code/regexp/) provided with *Kushman, Nate, and Regina Barzilay. "[Using semantic unification to generate regular expressions from natural language.](http://dspace.mit.edu/openaccess-disseminate/1721.1/79645)" North American Chapter of the Association for Computational Linguistics (NAACL), 2013.*, but I'm looking for more data.

I am also aware that there exist [different regular expression standards](http://dspace.mit.edu/openaccess-disseminate/1721.1/79645) (more precisely the POSIX standard isn't always respected) and I'm okay if the regexp output is not POSIX although I would prefer it was. By the same token I know that two regular expressions [can be equivalent](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/6954/903) just like two description written in English can be equivalents.

Ideally it would be great if each regexp comes with some positive and negative examples as well (e.g. for `s.*`, "hello" is a negative example, "salut" is a positive example), but it's okay if not.

Comment: Are you looking for more "data" or more "examples"? Have you considered something like the http://www.regular-expressions-cookbook.com/ which has samples you can download for free or one of the many RegEx sharing/library sites?

Comment: If you want a sentance explaining what a regex does, you might want to try [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=module&query=YAPE%3A%3ARegex%3A%3AExplain).  I'd also look to various test suites for perl modules if you want regex + what they're supposed to match.  Also, your examples make the assumption that you're already starting with a word; if you're not, you might need to prefix them with `\b` to start at a word boundry.